# How to dynamically deploy azure function via blob zip file via API

Tags: c#, azure, rest, deployment

I want to deploy the C# azure timer trigger function in the function app. I have zip files in my storage container in azure. Now I want to use that zip to deploy timer trigger functions in the function app. This process needs to complete by calling rest API. So that we can deploy as many functions as want dynamically.

I have tried it by powershell script. But for some reason in azure runbook, some powershell command is not supported. So that I want to make it possible via Rest API.

Comment: Once I answered a new comer's question, instead of accepting my answer he deleted the question, it turned out a homework question. From now on I will never answer a new comer's question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried it by powershell script. But for some reason in azure runbook, some powershell command is not supported.

As an alternative approach, I have tried this using Azure PowerShell and I could able to achieve this using `Invoke-WebRequest` where it downloads the content to the local folder and then use `Publish-AzWebapp` to push deployment from the uploaded .zip file. For demonstration purposes I have deployed 3 function apps using the below script.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>" -StorageAccountKey "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY>"
$a = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container "<CONTAINER_NAME>"

for($i=0; $i -le $a.Count-1; $i++)
{
    $Uri = "https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>/"+$a[$i].Name
    $Outfile = "/home/*****/"+$a[$i].Name
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -OutFile $Outfile
    Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP> -Name $a[$i].Name.substring(0, ($a[$i].Name).IndexOf(".")) -ArchivePath $a[$i].Name
}
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

Comment: Yes, this one is a possible way, and I have also tried it before. But as I said, it is great if we do the entire flow with rest API. Because I don't want to add a PowerShell script to my project as it creates more dependency.
But thanks for the answer. May be it will help to someone else. :)